# Hilbert dual space (inequality and reflexivity)

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V \subset H$ where $H$ is Hilbert space. Let $T:H^* \to V^*$ be the canonical map that restricts the domain of a functional in $H$ so that it's a functional in $V$.

How do I show that 
$$\lVert T\varphi \rVert_{V^*} \leq C\lVert \varphi \rVert_{H^*}$$
if $\lVert v \rVert_H \leq C\lVert v \rVert_V$?
I can't get it out...

Also, how to show that

> $Range(T)$ is dense in $V^*$ if $V$ is reflexive?

No idea where to start with this. I only know that reflexive means $V \equiv V^{**}$.

Comment: This is a rather bizarre question, since Hilbert spaces are all reflexive.

Comment: @ChrisEagle We can have $H=\ell^2(\Bbb C)$ and $V=\ell^1(\Bbb C)$, so $V$ is not necessarily a Hilbert space, and not necessarily reflexive.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo: when I made my comment, the question stated that $V$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Yes, I remember now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$We have for $\phi \in H^*$
\begin{align*} 
  \norm{T\phi}_{V^*} &= \sup_{\norm v_V = 1} \abs{(T\phi)(v)}\\
    &= \sup_{\norm v_V = 1} \abs{\phi(v)}\\
    &\le \sup_{\norm h_H \le C} \abs{\phi(h)} & \text{as }\{v \in V \mid \norm v_V = 1\} \subseteq \{h \in H \mid \norm h_H \le C\}\\
    &\le \sup_{\norm h_H \le C} \norm{\phi}_{H^*} \norm h_H\\
    &= C \norm{\phi}_{H^*}
\end{align*}
Note that we didn't use the Hilbert space property of $H$ or $V$ here, this works for general Banach spaces, which is also the context in which the second question makes sense, as Hilbert spaces are always reflexive. So let $V$ be a reflexive Banach space and $W := \overline{\operatorname{ran} T} \subseteq V^*$. We will show that every $\psi \in V^{**}$ with $\psi|_W = 0$ is zero on $V^*$. By Hahn-Banach, this suffices. So let $\psi \in V^{**}$ with $\psi|_W = 0$ be given, as $V$ is reflexive, there is a $v \in V$ with 
\[ \psi(v^* ) = v^* (v), \quad \text{all } v^* \in V^*. \]
We now have for each $\phi\in H^*$ that 
\[ 0  = \psi(T\phi) = (T\phi)(v) = \phi(v) \]
which is, by Hahn-Banach, only possible for $v = 0$ (If $v \ne 0$, we could extend the functional $\mathbb K\cdot v \to \mathbb K$, $\lambda v \mapsto \lambda\cdot \|v\|$ continously to a $\phi \in H^*$, then $\phi(v) = \|v\| \ne 0$). So $\psi = 0$ and $W = V^*$, as wished.

Comment: Thanks, please can you expand on the last sentence. I think my H-B is different to yours..

Comment: @hopo2 I added something.

Answer (score 2):

Let $v\in V$. As $(T\varphi)(v)=\varphi(v)$ if $\varphi\in H^*$, we have 
$$|T(\varphi)(v)|=|\varphi(v)|\leq \lVert \varphi \rVert_H\cdot\lVert v\rVert_H\leq C\lVert \varphi \rVert_H\cdot\lVert v\rVert_V,$$
which gives for $v\neq 0$:
$$\frac{|T(\varphi)(v)|}{\lVert v\rVert_V}\leq C\lVert \varphi \rVert_H,$$
which gives, after having taken the supremum, the wanted result.

For the second question, let $L$ a linear functional on $V^*$ (hence an element of $V^{**}$) which vanishes on $T(V^*)$. Let $J\colon V\to V^{**}$ the canonical inclusion; here it's surjective, hence $L=J(l)$ for some $l\in V$. We have 
$$\langle L,T\varphi\rangle_{V^{**},V^*}=\langle J(l),T\varphi\rangle_{V^{**},V^*}=\langle T\varphi,l\rangle_{V^*,V}=0.$$
As $l\in V$, we have for all $\varphi\in H^*$, $\varphi(l)=0$ so $l=0$, and we conclude by Hahn-Banach theorem.