# Hilbert space and its dual

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have an elliptic equation in the form $$-\Delta u + u =F(u).$$ For any $\phi \in C^{\infty}_{0}$ we rewrite the elliptic equation in weak form $$\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left(-\Delta u + u\right)\phi dx=\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} F \phi dx.$$ Then, thanks to the definitions of $L^{2}$ and $H^{1}$ norms we obtain $$\left\|u\right\|_{H^{1}}\left\|\phi\right\|_{L^{2}}\leq \left\|F\right\|_{L^{2}}\left\|\phi\right\|_{L^{2}} \\ \left\|u\right\|_{H^{1}}\leq \left\|F\right\|_{L^{2}}.$$
Here, I want to understand the relationship between $H^1$ and its dual space $H^*$. Is it possible to see $\left\|u\right\|_{H^{1}}\leq \left\|u\right\|_{H^{*}}$ and/or $\left\|F\right\|_{L^{2}}\leq \left\|u\right\|_{H^{*}}$?

P.S.:I saw a similiar question in: [Hilbert dual space (inequality and reflexivity)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219630/hilbert-dual-space-inequality-and-reflexivity), but I couldn't understand well.

Comment: The dual of a Hilbert space may be isometrically identified with the initial Hilbert space via [Riesz representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

The situation you have to keep in mind while approaching these problems is: let $V$ be a Banach space, countinuosly embedded in the Hilbert space $H$ ($V \hookrightarrow H$), then we have: $V \hookrightarrow H \cong H^* \hookrightarrow V^*$.

This is the prototype of your situation, in which $V = H^1$, $H = L^2$ and $V^* = H^{-1}$.